# PDO::PARAM for dates?

Tags: php, mysql, date, types, pdo

Does some `PDO::PARAM_???` exist which can be used for dates or timestamps?

Sample code:

```
$sql = "UPDATE my_table SET current_date = :date WHERE id = 43";
$statement = $pdo->prepare ($sql);
$statement->bindValue (":date", strtotime (date ("Y-m-d H:i:s")), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->execute ();
```

Answer (score 117, accepted):

When writing a date in an SQL query, you are writing it as a string; you have to do the same with prepared statements, and use `PDO::PARAM_STR`, like you did in the portion of code you proposed.

And for the "timestamp", if by "timestamp" you mean:

- The MySQL timestamp data-type: it's the same, you'll pass it as a `string`
- The PHP Unix timestamp, which is an integer: you'll pass it an `int`.

Comment: What in case of ms precision?

Comment: @ManuelSchneid3r, not for timestamps: "Unix time (also known as POSIX time or UNIX Epoch time) is a system for describing a point in time. It is the number of **seconds** that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970, minus leap seconds." / https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: Is easier that way, just define in the database the filed as VARCHAR(size) and send the variable with date("Y/m/d") with your time zone and if you want the hour date("h:i:s")

Comment: A date is fomatted as dd.mm. yyyy . Where I live at least. Storing dates as strings is not recommended as there is quite a risk they will be interpreted wrong. This might be the reason why the database engine angostic PDO library stayed clear of implementing a date or datetime value type. What might work in MySQL or MariaDB, might not in Progress or SQLServer.

Comment: @theking2 nobody's talking about *storing* date as string here. Only about using the correct string representation in the SQL. This answer is all correct.

Answer (score 19):

Simply creating the date using php date function should fix this issue for you.

```
$handle->execute(array(":date"=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date)), PDO::PARAM_STR));
```

> Edit: Please note though, that `strtotime`
>   (http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) can't handle every
>   kind of date formats.

Answer (score 7):

Nope. Treat date as a string.

Answer (score -2):

You have to treat the date as string, but you can create a function to check if is a valid date before pass it as a param.
Like this:

```
function checkValidDate($date, $format = "dd-mm-yyyy"){
            if($format === "dd-mm-yyyy"){
            $day = (int) substr($date,0,2);
            $month = (int) substr($date, 3,2);
            $year = (int) substr($date, 6,4);

        }else if($format === "yyyy-mm-dd"){
            $day = (int) substr($date,8,2);
            $month = (int) substr($date, 5,2);
            $year = (int) substr($date, 0,4);
        }

        return checkdate($month, $day, $year);
}
```

Comment: not the way to go, Diego. There are date format functions in every RDBMS I've encountered. Watch this: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/date_format/

Answer (score -2):

A complete section to properly store a DateTime value (as a string) in a RDBMS:

```
/** @const string app_date_format expected date format in the PHP domain (Swiss) */
define( 'app_date_format', 'd.m.Y' ); 

/** @var PDOConnection $db */
$db = new \PDO( $dsn, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_options );

/** @var DateTime $date */
$date = \DateTime::createFromFormat( app_date_format, '30.11.2020' );

$stmt = $db-> prepare(
    "UPDATE `test`
    SET `test_date` = STR_TO_DATE(:date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s' )
    WHERE `test`.`test_id` = :id"
);

$id = 1;
$stmt->bindValue( ':id', $id );
$stmt->bindValue( ':date', $date-> format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s'));
$stmt->execute() or die( $stmt-> errorInfo()[2] );
```

Tested with PHP 7.4.25; MariaDB 10.6.4

Comment: the code is buggy and misleading. A lowercase constant is against the standard. And the answer doesn't even touch the question asked

Comment: @YourCommonSense Where are the bugs? Where are the standards? Where is the mislead. You need to elaborate Your Common Sense.

Comment: @your-common-sense seriously. where?

Comment: A year passed, and you still didn't learn it yourself? Well, that shameful `or die( $db-> error );` for example. But the main point, this STR_TO_DATE of yours is ridiculously redundant. The whole world around you makes it just `test_date = :date` as required by MySQL.

Comment: dates are not strings

Comment: In SQL, they are.

Answer (score -5):

This worked for me.

```
//MS SQL
$sql = "UPDATE my_table SET current_date = GETDATE() WHERE id = 43";
$statement = $pdo->prepare ($sql);
//$statement->bindParam (":date", strtotime (date ("Y-m-d H:i:s")), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->execute ();
```

Comment: You are not helping much by not showing how to bind the param to a PHP-generated date instead of the mysql GETDATE function...