# PDO BIND a DATE MYSQL - How to pass a date ?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a problem

When i use this in PHP:

```
$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(b_slotStart) FROM cp_booking "
                . "WHERE b_date=:date"
                . "AND :start BETWEEN cp_booking.b_slotStart "
                . "AND cp_booking.b_slotEnd "
                . "OR :stop BETWEEN cp_booking.b_slotStart AND cp_booking.b_slotEnd");

        $stmt1->bindParam(':start',$time->format('H:i'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt1->bindParam(':stop',$time->add($interval)->format('H:i'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt1->bindParam(':date',$date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt1->execute();
        $slotStart = $stmt1->fetchColumn();
```

I get an error with the :date

but if i instead of :date write '2016-1-14' it works like a charm.

how do i pass a time string in PDO ?

I get this error:

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '? BETWEEN cp_booking.b_slotStart AND cp_booking.b_slotEnd OR ? BETWEEN cp_bookin' at line 1' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/getData.php:59 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/getData.php(59): PDO->prepare('SELECT COUNT(b_...') #1 {main}
```

If i put '' around :date in the query i get this error:

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/getData.php:63 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/getData.php(63): PDOStatement->bindParam(':date', '2016-1-14', 2) #1 {main}
```

I am a newbie when we talk about PDO

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23607752/3166303

Comment: You had better show us an `echo $date` as it all depends on what is in that variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PDO::PARAM for dates?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374631/pdoparam-for-dates)

Comment: 2016-1-14 is in that variable, but it needs the ' '

Comment: You're missing a space after :date, just FYI

Comment: The f'''' space did it!!!!!!!!! I have looked and looked and looked.... FFS

Comment: `WHERE b_date=:date" . "AND` reads as `WHERE b_date=:dateAND`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I think I see the issue, just a typo probably when you replaced a hard coded date with the parameter

This line

```
"WHERE b_date=:date"
```

need a space after `:date` like this

```
"WHERE b_date=:date "
```

Comment: Personally I find it more secure to put the space in front of multiple line SQL statements:
"SELECT COUNT(b_slotStart) FROM cp_booking"
. " WHERE b_date=:date"
 . "    AND :start BETWEEN cp_booking.b_slotStart"

Comment: @Mark1 Me too :)