# PHP/MySQL Compare against a date

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running into a little issue concerning a datetime picker and MySQL.

I have a PHP script that *should* get records before (and including) the selected day. However, the dataset returns empty.

Here's the SQL part of the script:

```
$sql = 'SELECT `pro_title`,
               `pro_part_number`,
               `name` AS flag_name,
               `old_val`,
               `new_val`
        FROM `products`
        INNER JOIN `flags` ON `id` = `pro_flag_id`
        INNER JOIN `flag_history` ON `pro_part_number` = `part`
        WHERE `pro_flag_id` IN(:flags)
        AND STR_TO_DATE(`ts`, "%y-%m-%d") <= :dateTs;';
```

I then use PDO to bind the params:

```
array(
    ':flags' => implode(',', $flags), # this outputs 1,2,3
    ':dateTs' => $date # this outputs 2019-04-30
)
```

I've also tried changing `<=` to `>=` to no avail (not that it should work, but thought I'd try).

I've come across a good few SO posts but nothing has actually got me there. Here is the description of the `flag_history` table (where `ts` is stored)

```
MariaDB [mastern]> describe `flag_history`;
+---------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| part    | varchar(25) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| ts      | datetime    | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| old_val | int(4)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| new_val | int(4)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

And some example data:

```
MariaDB [mastern]> select * from `flag_history` order by `id` desc limit 5;
+-------+----------+---------------------+---------+---------+
| id    | part     | ts                  | old_val | new_val |
+-------+----------+---------------------+---------+---------+
| 24026 | PART-001 | 2019-04-30 09:42:22 |       0 |       3 |
| 24025 | PART-002 | 2019-04-30 09:42:22 |       0 |       3 |
| 24024 | PART-003 | 2019-04-30 09:42:22 |       0 |       3 |
| 24023 | PART-004 | 2019-04-30 09:42:22 |       0 |       3 |
| 24022 | PART-005 | 2019-04-30 09:42:22 |       0 |       3 |
+-------+----------+---------------------+---------+---------+
```

Then, using PART-001 to make sure the flag_id is actually set:

```
MariaDB [mastern]> select `pro_flag_id` from `products` where `pro_part_number` = "PART-001";
+-------------+
| pro_flag_id |
+-------------+
|           3 |
+-------------+
```

So I'm not really sure what's going wrong, the logic and everything to me (MySQL newb) looks like it should work but it's giving me empty data. I also tried changing the `INNER JOIN`'s to `LEFT JOIN`'s but again, didn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: PDO bind for date perhaps:.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2374631/pdoparam-for-dates

Comment: @DirkScholten good spot! Corrected in code + Q. Still didn't fix it unfortunately

Comment: @RichardHousham tried via binding - adding `PDO::PARAM_STR` to the `:dateTs` bind. Again nothing :/

Comment: @treyBake Can you put together a DB fiddle with your tables and their values, so we can play around and help debug it?

Comment: @Qirel just answered! haha but where would I go (in future) for a good DB fiddle?

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/ or http://sqlfiddle.com/ is what I've been using before. When asking SQL questions, it's always helpful to create a fiddle with your table/data and current query. Makes troubleshooting easier for those of us trying to answer :-)

Comment: @Qirel ah that's pretty awesome, bookmarked! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to *solve* it. As I'm really reading the `flag_history` table, I changed the main `SELECT` focus to `flag_history`, revised SQL:

```
$sql = 'SELECT `old_val`, `new_val`, `ts`, `flags`.`name` AS flag_name, `pro_part_number`, `pro_title`
        FROM `flag_history`
        INNER JOIN `products` ON `pro_part_number` = `part`
        INNER JOIN `flags` ON `pro_flag_id` = `flags`.`id`
        WHERE `ts` <= :dateTs;';
```

I slowly added in the `INNER JOIN`'s and managed to get it working when using `flag_history`. I think the issue actually may have been down to the `id` field. Being an ambiguous field (`flags` and `flag_history` have the `id` column). Weirdly, I wasn't getting that error though (maybe as I wasn't selecting). Either way managed to resolve it by being more specific with my select and going from the read-table rather than joining it.

On a further note, removing the `flags` segment from the JOIN shows the constraint error. So my guess is that it didn't show first time as I was reading from a different table.